# Testing Android Instant apps Internat Test

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have a published application and I want to try instant App.
To simplify the use case I needed to create a dedicated module in my project. This module has enabled to Instant App, same package and version code lower than the installable app. Applinks have been added to the manifest. Today published app already has applinks working.
When build released signed version, I have two app modules (installable app and instant app module). These two modules have been place in internal test channel as a release.
I want to try my instant app but when I go to play store (as internal tester) I do not have the "Try Now" button.
https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle#test-publish-internal-test-track

Some of you al ready had this issue and know what could explain this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that your instant release is active? It can be checked within Google Play Console > Setup > Advanced Settings > Release types, under Google Play Instant.

Once active, it may take a bit of time to propagate to the store on your device.

I would also make sure to access the internal testing page by using the "Join on the web" link, available to be copied under Testing > Internal testing > Testers > How testers join your test.

Comment: The try Now button just pop up. Did not know that need time to propagate :/
I have configured universal link as my published application on my instant app. Do you know if it is possible to test it ? (well-known file already live and working)

Comment: Nope, I have no experience using universal links; I don't know whether they can be tested using internal builds.